# return values from a function got Object required error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function like this:

```
'find a value from excel

Function findInExcel(PATH, value) As Range
Dim oApp_Excel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim column As Long
Dim rngSize As Range


Set oApp_Excel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
oApp_Excel.DisplayAlerts = False
oApp_Excel.Visible = False
Set oBook = oApp_Excel.Workbooks.Open(PATH)

Set rngSize = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=value)

MsgBox rngSize.row 'it show a correct value.
oBook.Close True
Set oBook = Nothing
oApp_Excel.Quit

Set findInExcel = rngSize

End Function
```

It work fine. but when I want to use it in another function I got this error:

```
Object required

Dim rr As Range

Set rr = findInExcel(filePath, "5611")
MsgBox rr.column
```

Comment: You cannot have a range object that refers to a range in a closed workbook.

Comment: I want to get column and row value. How can I do?

Comment: Store those values in Long variables and return them, not a range object.

Comment: Do it in the first function, and return an array. First array element being the range, if you still need it, the second two what you need... Or only the other piece of information. **Not as Range**. As array, for instance.

Comment: If you need the found cell value you should return it as Variant. If you need all the column (value) place it in an array and return the array (of values). `Dim arr, LastR as Long` And use it in your first function: `lastR =  oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(cells.coount, rngSize.column).End(xlUp).row' followed by `arr = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").range(cells(1, rngSize.column),cells(lastR, rngSize.column)).Value` Then `findInExcel = arr` But fully qualify `cells(1, x)`. The best way would be to declare and set the sheet (`oBook.Sheets("Sheet1")`) and use it to compact the code...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom `Type` and return the details you need from that.

```vb
Function findInExcel(PATH As String, value As String) As CellData
    Dim oApp_Excel As Excel.Application
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rngSize As Range
    
    Set oApp_Excel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
    oApp_Excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    oApp_Excel.Visible = False
    Set oBook = oApp_Excel.Workbooks.Open(PATH)
    
    Set rngSize = oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=value)
    
    Dim cellInfo As CellData
    cellInfo.Column = rngSize.Column
    cellInfo.Row = rngSize.Row
    cellInfo.TextValue = rngSize.Text
    
    oBook.Close True
    Set oBook = Nothing
    oApp_Excel.Quit
    
    Set findInExcel = cellInfo 
End Function
```